# How to get user input to override price in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I've been working at this all day now. After looking through a ton of documentation this is what I've come up with so far... I think I'm close but I'm hung up on passing the variable from JS to PHP via a Cookie. What am I missing here? I should mention this is being done with WooCommerce on WordPress.

There is an input field that shows up when someone chooses a specific variation from the drop down on a product page.
**EDIT: Added better context. This `input` is nested.**

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="28664" data-product_variations=...">
    <div class="single_variation">
        <span class="price">
            <div class="custom-amount-trigger">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="number" id="custom_amount" class="custom-amount" placeholder="Enter Whole Number"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then when the input looses focus (`onblur`), it is supposed to create the cookie. This code is part of an already working script in my footer.php. I've added the code below to the script to create the cookie. I have a feeling this is where things are going wrong (?).

```
$(document).on('onblur','custom-amount', function(){
    price = "price=" + escape(document.getElementByID("custom_amount").value) + "; ";
document.cookie = "customAmount=" + price + "path=/";
})
```

Then, in my functions.php, I have the following, which should get the cookie info.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price' );

function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $custom_price = $_COOKIE["customAmount"];
    $target_product_ids = array (31708, 31418, 28825);

    foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

        if ( in_array( $value['variation_id'], $target_product_ids ) ) {
            $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting a cookie instead of just submitting the form with the values entered?

Comment: @ElefantPhace : good question. The `input` is being created by JavaScript in `footer.php`, not WooCommerce. I'm not really sure how else to get the variable. If you have another idea, please let me know. I know this seems like a round about way to get the variable. I'm working with code that was setup by another person who did not document anything but made a ton of changes to the code. So I'm feeling a bit buried. I'm definitely open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
$('#custom_amount').on('blur', function(){
    price = "price=" + escape($("#custom_amount").val()) + "; ";
    document.cookie = "customAmount=" + price + "path=/";
 })
```

Assuming you are using jquery

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I am using jquery. I tried your code but it didn't work. I did notice that you entered the letter "m" twice in the first `#custom_amount`. That's because I kept finding myself doing that yesterday. After fixing it, the code still didn't work.